# Error message: "is_scalar_character(new_value) is not TRUE" in officer-package R

Tags: r, officer

I wanna replace text by keywords via officer
Until now I had good experiences with that package. And I could work easily in it.
Today I encountered a problem, an error message a never had before and cannot solve on my own:

**Error in body_replace_all_text(., "Zahl", data_base$Einheiten[[x]]) :
is_scalar_character(new_value) is not TRUE**

What can I do?

```
library(dplyr)
print_docx_data_base <- lapply(1:nrow(data_base), function(x) {
  # empty_docs <- officer::read_docx()
  # empty_docs <- officer::read_docx(docx_template)
  empty_docs <- officer::read_docx("Teilnahmebestaetigung_template.docx")
  sample_doc <- empty_docs %>% body_replace_all_text("Person",data_base$person[[x]])
  sample_doc <- empty_docs %>% body_replace_all_text("Veranstaltungsname",data_base$Kursart[[x]])
  sample_doc <- empty_docs %>% body_replace_all_text("Zahl",data_base$Einheiten[[x]])
  sample_doc <- empty_docs %>% body_replace_all_text("Daten",data_base$Tage[[x]])
  sample_doc <- empty_docs %>% body_replace_all_text("Ort",data_base$Ort[[x]])
  sample_doc <- empty_docs %>% body_replace_all_text("Datum",format(Sys.Date(),format = "%d.%m.%Y"))
  sample_doc <- empty_docs %>% body_replace_all_text("Firmenname",data_base$Firmenname[[x]])
  sample_doc <- empty_docs %>% body_replace_all_text("Strasse",data_base$Strasse[[x]])
  sample_doc <- empty_docs %>% body_replace_all_text("PLZ",as.character(data_base$PLZ[[x]]))
  print(sample_doc, target = file_name[[x]])
  if (any(list.files() == file_name[[x]])) 
  {cat(paste("File is saved.\n"))}
}
)
```

This is how the template looks like:
[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpJWw.png]

Some test data:

```
data_base <- structure(list(nr = c(3, 1, 4, 2), 
               kursteilnehmer = paste(c("Some name"),c(1:4)), 
               titel_1 = c("NA", "Magª. Dr. ", NA, "Magª."), 
               titel_2 = c("NA", "NA", "M.A.", "NA"), 
               Kursart = rep("Some course", 4), 
               Ort = rep("Some City", 4), 
               Firmenname = rep("Some company", 4), 
               Strasse = rep("Some street", 4), PLZ = rep("Some ZIP", 4), 
               person = c(paste(data_base$titel_1,kursteilnehmer,data_base$titel_2)),
               Einheiten = c(4, 5, 4, 4), 
               Tage = c("23.09.2022, 30.09.2022, 07.10.2022, 14.10.2022", 
                        "23.09.2022, 30.09.2022, 07.10.2022, 14.10.2022, 21.10.2022", 
                        "23.09.2022, 30.09.2022, 14.10.2022, 21.10.2022",
                        "23.09.2022, 30.09.2022, 14.10.2022, 21.10.2022")), 
               row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `body_replace_all_text()` function of the officer package seems to only accept characters. The `Einheiten` variable is numerical so you need to apply `as.character()` before using it as a replacement value :

```
sample_doc <- empty_docs %>% 
  body_replace_all_text("Zahl", as.character(data_base$Einheiten[[x]]))
```